# How to change GET variables using .htaccess in wordpress for pretty URL

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know how to change URL in `PHP` but I am not an expert in WordPress.

I have this URL:

`domain.com/parent-page/child-page-here/?id=SomeText`

and I want this

domain.com/parent-page/child-page-here/Some Text:

I changed `.htaccess` but its not working here is my `.htaccess` code

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^parent-page/child-page/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) parent-page/child-page/?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use the .htaccess as Wordpress comes with the feature you are required. All you have to do is change the permalink  as [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwiCtfr-wZLVAhWDFJQKHemlBUAQFggvMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcodex.wordpress.org%2FSettings_Permalinks_Screen&usg=AFQjCNFSA5jq0Lyzq7-TBH03es3ihcFB2g) from the admin dashboard.

Comment: I am using  post-name from parmalink. i am sending data in id="text " and fetching data from custom page $_GET[''id"] and sending this value to the database for results

Comment: could you please tell how to change the URL from .htaccess files and doing this now RewriteRule ^parent-page/child-page/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ parent-page/child-page/index.php/?id=$1 [L] but its not working

Answer (score 0):

@mapmalith is correct, with WordPress you can simply change the permalinks in your settings.

However, if for whatever reason you're unable to do this, then you can use the following inside your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^parent-page/child-page-here/([^/]*)$ /parent-page/child-page-here/?id=$1 [L]
```

It will leave you with the following URL: `domain.com/parent-page/child-page-here/SomeText`. Just make sure you clear your cache before you test this.

Obviously you will need to rename the directories to the correct names.

Comment: i already select post-name form dashboard and i just tried you code its not working its giving me Internal Server Error

Comment: this is my .htaccess file(# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^aircraft-gallery/aircraft-gallery-class/([^/]*)$ aircraft-gallery/aircraft-gallery-class/?id=$1 [L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress)

Comment: are you there..?